# How to add a prop to the last element of an array of jsx elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- I want to have `isActive` props for the last element in the array as **true** and rest as **false**
- initially i am setting all as **true** but i want to modify it dynamically depending upon the length of the array
- That is if there is only 1 element i want to have `isActive` as **true** for the 1st `Number` component

**Example**

- Suppose i have 5 elements in **number** array then i want to have `number[3]` having `isActive` **true** and rest as false

please help stuck over this array manipulation :((

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Numbers extends Component {
    render() {
        const correctGuesses = this.props.correctGuesses
        let number = [<Number guess={'1-100'} key={0 + Math.random} isActive={true}/>]
        for(let i=0 ; i < correctGuesses ; i++) {
            number.push(<Number guess={`1-${i+2}00`} key={i} isActive={true}/>)
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {number}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last element to have isActive props true you can use this:

```
Import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Numbers extends Component {
    render() {
        const correctGuesses = this.props.correctGuesses
        let number
        if(correctGuesses === 0) {
            number = [<Number guess={`1-100`} key={Math.random} isActive={true}/>]
        } else if (correctGuesses > 0) {
            number = [<Number guess={`1-100`} key={Math.random} isActive={false}/>]
        }

        for(let i=0 ; i < correctGuesses ; i++) {
            if(i === correctGuesses-1)
                number.push(<Number guess={`1-${i+2}00`} key={i} isActive={true}/>)
            else
                number.push(<Number guess={`1-${i+2}00`} key={i} isActive={false}/>)
        }


        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {number}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: dont assign number to an empty array i need it to render something if `correctGuesses is 0`

Comment: other than that its working so include that in your answer and i will accept it thanks much :)

Comment: also we need to set `isActive` props of 1st element as `false` if length is more than 1

Comment: I have incorporated all the changes that you wanted, this will add a component if correctGuesses is 0 and if correctGuesses is greater than 1 than 1st element will not be Active

Comment: uhh no this is not working :( i need to display all my `Number` components starting from 1st to last and doing this makes javascript ignore the 1st element when `correctGuesses` is not 0 :( i will give you an upvote for trying tho :)

Comment: I got it working.. lemme edit your answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Props are immutable once you assign them. One way would be to set the value to an object and then to set its children value on the go:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Numbers extends Component {
    render() {
        const correctGuesses = this.props.correctGuesses;
        let lastActive = {value: true};
        let number = [<Number guess={'1-100'} key={0 + Math.random} isActive={lastActive}/>]
        for(let i=0 ; i < correctGuesses ; i++) {
            lastActive = {value: true};
            number.push(<Number guess={`1-${i+2}00`} key={i} isActive={lastActive}/>)
        }
        
        lastActive.value = false;
        

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {number}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Throws an error .. cant set property of undefined :(( in line `lastActive.value = false`

Comment: oh yeah, didn't see you are setting initial value outside the loop. see edit